# How do I get File.WriteAllText() to save to website root level instead of local storage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.io.file

I am currently building a website that I am running from a memory stick. However it will be uploaded to a server soon. I am using the File.WriteAllText() method to save to a text file but it wont pick up the root level of my website to add to the text file. It just directs me to the C drive on my laptop.
Here is my method code

```
File.WriteAllText("../Page_Text/Campaign_Title.txt", txtCampaignTitle.Text);
```

This is the exception that gets thrown

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Page_Text\Campaign_Title.txt'.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

*Sorry was accidentally deleted still in need of solution*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Server.MapPath("~") returns the physical path to the root of the application

```
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + @"\Page_Text\Campaign_Title.txt", txtCampaignTitle.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Or `Server.MapPath("~\Page_Text\Campaign_Title.txt")`